# Centering a div within a div over content (easy upvotes)

Tags: css, html, web, center

I have made the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hxQE4/

See how the right arrow pushes the image down.  I would like the right arrow to be centered in the large div regardless of the size of the image inside of it.  I can not use absolute positioning but I would like the arrow centered relative to the div (about 300px down from the start of the div) regardless of what image is inside there.

Comment: Include problem code in the post, not just a jsfiddle URL (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84342/answer-that-only-contains-a-link-to-jsfiddle)

Comment: Pretty sure saying "(easy upvotes)" stopped anyone from reading this

Comment: One of the parts that may break depending on browser is your span.slider-right. Inline elements(spans) cannot contain block level elements(divs). You should change the spans to divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick and dirty solution would be to set the containing span for the button (.slider-right) to a height of 100%, then apply a "position: relative; top: 50%;" to the button (.slider-right .circle).  That will put the top of the button at the half way mark, so you may need to tweak it a bit to 48% or whatever looks best.

You'd also need to remove the top margin from the containing span if you went that route or the button will be dropped down by that amount.

I also noticed you have div's inside of span's.  You should avoid placing block level elements (like div's) within inline level elements (like span's).  It would likely fail validation as-is.


**UPDATED**  The css:

```
.slider-right {
position: relative;
float: right;
height: 100%;
margin-top: 0px;
position: relative;
right: 6px;
width: 32px;
z-index: 30;
}

.circle{
position: relative;
top: 48%;
display:table;
line-height:30px;
width:10px;
height:10px;
padding:3px 5px 3px 7px;
border:2px solid #CFC5CD;
border-radius:21px;
background: #000000; /* Old browsers */
opacity: .99;
}
```

Comment: That did not work.  Also when the spans are changed to divs the arrow gets messed up.

Comment: It works for me... see the css I added to my original post, with the css of what I was referring to.

Comment: It didn't work but you get the upvotes for trying

Comment: Still works for me...  http://jsfiddle.net/hxQE4/2/

Comment: Better yet, with the spans converted to divs:  http://jsfiddle.net/hxQE4/3/